# How to get plotly to not ignore my axis settings?

Tags: python, plotly

```
import plotly.plotly as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go
from plotly.offline import init_notebook_mode, iplot
init_notebook_mode(connected=True)

import numpy as np

x, y, z = np.random.multivariate_normal(np.array([0,0,0]), np.eye(3), 200).transpose()
trace1 = go.Scatter3d(
    x=x,
    y=y,
    z=z,
    mode='markers',
    marker=dict(
        size=12,
        line=dict(
            color='rgba(217, 217, 217, 0.14)',
            width=0.5
        ),
        opacity=0.8
    )
)

data = [trace1]
layout = go.Layout(
    margin=dict(
        l=0,
        r=0,
        b=0,
        t=0
    ),
    xaxis=dict(type='log',
               autorange=True,
               title="L1")
)
fig = go.Figure(data=data, layout=layout)
iplot(fig, filename='simple-3d-scatter')
```

This is an example from the docs, https://plot.ly/python/3d-scatter-plots/ that I slightly modified to

- make the xaxis log scale (following [this](https://plot.ly/python/log-plot/#logarithmic-axes)) and
- change the x axis label (following [this](https://plot.ly/python/figure-labels/#styling-axes-labels))

However, Plotly seems to be (silently) ignoring my axis settings, as I am getting this and not getting any errors/warnings:

[image]

which you might notice, is neither log scale nor the `L1` axis label that I want it to have.

How do I fix this? Python 3.6.8, Plotly version 3.6.1, plotting in Jupyter notebook (offline mode).

---

Trying with plotly 3.3 in a virtualenv:

[image]

Comment: Try to create a virtualenv in Plotly with version 2.7 or 3.3. (https://plot.ly/python/getting-started/). Plotly using virtualenv

Comment: @RajMehta Nope, doesn't work with plotly3.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specify axis attributes within a `scene` dict, as following:

```
layout = go.Layout(
    margin=dict(
        l=0,
        r=0,
        b=0,
        t=0
    ),
    scene=dict(
        xaxis=dict(
           type='log',
           autorange=True,
           title='L1')
    )
)
```

[image]

Comment: thanks that works. not quite sure what this isn't mentioned in the docs or I'm just blind.